# HQL equivalent for postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, hql

I am trying to figure out the HQL equivalent of my query that has 2 subqueries, what I'm trying to do is I am getting the max amount for the past 6 months and then group them by month, and then I will get the average of the past 6 month result. And since the rows have version column, I also need to get maxed version for that specific row.

Here is my query, I'm using postgres by the way. Any help would be appreciated as I'm really having a hard time. Thanks in advance.

```
select avg(amount1) as maxField1 from 
 (
      select max(amount1) as amount1 from table1 a
      where a.id = :id
      and a.date between :startDate
      and :endDate
      and a.version =
      (
           select max(b.version) from table1 b
           where a.id = b.id
           and a.date = b.date
      )
      group by to_char(a.date, 'YYYYMM')
 );
```

Comment: HQL, and JPA too, allow for subqueries only in the SELECT or WHERE clauses. Subqueries in the FROM clause are not allowed, see: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries. You need to rewrite this query moving subqueries into WHERE clasue, but it maybe very difficult or even impossible in this case. Why don't just use a native query, it is the easiest option ?

Comment: Hi krokodilko, I followed your suggestion and used the native query and utilized @SqlResultSetMapping(name="...Result", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(...., thank you for your help!